# getting multiple calculations for differant variables to be resulted to other variables and be displayed as laple on the GUI in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am working on a program that is a GUI that takes multiple inputs from the user and apply mathematical calculations on them and displays the results. I defined all the mathematical calculations in a defined function and call this function by a button that command is the function, but what I get is no display for the results on the wanted places on the GUI.

Here is the code of the defined function:

```
xxx6=tk.StringVar
xx7=tk.StringVar
entry6 = tk.Entry(window,textvariable=xxx6).place(x=160,y=175)
entry7 = tk.Entry(window,textvariable=xx7).place(x=160,y=215)



def calculate (*args):

    
    xx66=float(xxx6)
    xxx7=float(xx7)
    ctdi100ppp=(ppp12/xx66)
    ctdi100ccc=(x8d/xx6)
    ctdiww=((0.33333333*ctdi100ccc)+(0.666666667*ctdi100ppp))
    ctdivolv=(ctdiww/xxx7)

    print( ctdiww, ctdivolv,ctdi100ccc,ctdi100ppp)

    ctdiwwww.config (Text=str(ctdiww))
    ctdivolvv.config(Text=str(ctdivolv))
    c100ppp.config(text=str(ctdi100ppp))
    ctdi100cccc.config(text=str(ctdi100ccc))

cal=tk.Button(window,
     text= "calculate"
     ,font=("arial" , 12 ),
     background= "green"
      ,width=10
      ,height=2,command=calculate).place(x=450,y=300)

c100ppp=tk.Label(window,text=""
    ,font=("arial" , 12 ),background="red").place(x=490,y=140)

ctdi100cccc=tk.Label(window,text=""
    ,font=("arial" , 12 ),background="red").place(x=490,y=90)

ctdiwwww=tk.Label(window,text=" "
    ,font=("arial" , 12 ),background="red").place(x=490,y=190)

ctdivolvv=tk.Label(window,text=""
  ,font=("arial" , 12 ),background="red").place(x=490,y=240)
```

Don't know why, but it keeps stuck on this error `float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'type'` or that `get` requires more arguments (self)` error

Screenshot showing error message:

[image: screenshot showing error message]

Comment: There's a difference between `StringVar` and `StringVar`, and between `Text=` and `text=`.

Comment: @Bryan: There's no difference between `StringVar` and `StringVar`.

Comment: Ah! Sorry for the typo. There's a difference between `StringVar` and `StringVar()`

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot for your help I changed it to 'StringVar()' and actually it passed this error but still fall in another one which is [ float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'StringVar']  for the line { xx66=float(xx6)}

Comment: @Ahmad: You have to pass the current value of the `StringVar`: i.e. `{xx66=float(xx6.get())}`. However, also note that `float()` doesn't work with empty strings so you will likely have to check for that.